# Spring security no explicit mapping for /error

Tags: spring, spring-security, http-status-code-404

Basically when I go to localhost:8080/login I get the following 404 page:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Aug 16 13:25:42 CEST 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

My dependencies in pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My security config:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http

            .addFilterBefore(new CorsFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .failureHandler(new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler())
            .successHandler(new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();

}
```

Everything else works just fine. I have checked the structure of the project and all controllers are in a subpackage to the location of the Application.

Comment: Can you share `login.jsp` page ?

Comment: I don't have one, would this result in a default being used or will it not work at all? I know I had a working login page earlier.

Edit: To clarify, I could go to localhost:8080/login and login, I am certain I did not have a `login.jsp`

Comment: do you have any `.jsp` page ? if yes, then give me their relative path.

Comment: I do not have any.